# Highcharts : How to use setData with a string obtained by ajax?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to update my chart using ajax but the setData method need an array and I only have a string so it doesn't work.

here is my code

```
$(".chooseService a").click(function() {
                            $("span.currentService").html($(this).html());
                            $.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard/ws/charge/repartition/jour/'+$(this).html(), 
                                function(data) {
                                    // setData (Array<Mixed> data, [Boolean redraw])
                                    chartDay.series[0].setData(data);
                            });
                        });
```

data is a formatted string like

```
 [[1356995280000,183.0],[1356995520000,573.0],[1356995760000,243.0]]
```

Would someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse your JSON string into the variable data.

> data = JSON.parse(data);

If you have trouble using the JSON method:
http://caniuse.com/json

Answer (score 0):

when you return the result from the server side you can format the content to be a JSON type

```
header ('Content-type: text / json');
header ('Content-type: application / json');
```

Then you can convert this result to evaluate it properly the javascript from the client side.

```
jQuery.parseJSON (this.responseString);
```

If you want an array like this in can use [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740775/php-return-array-into-javascript)