# How to display multiple json_encode on pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

Hi guys so im using Chart.js to create a pie chart and im getting the data from the database:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Questions Asked", "Low Confidence", "No Answer", "Missing Intent"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '#',
            data: {!! json_encode($data) !!},
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
            ],
        }]
    },
    options: {

    }
});
</script>
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

so as you guys can see in the script line:

`data: {!! json_encode($data) !!}`,

this will view only one column.. how do i write so it will show another 3 columns which are

`{!! json_encode($data1) !!}`, `{!! json_encode($data2) !!}`, `{!! json_encode($data3) !!}`

Currently the pie chart is only showing data from one column

Comment: your code snippet doesn't even run

Answer (score 0):

A pie chart is only a one to one relationship between label and data.  In your example your labels are:

```
labels: ["Questions Asked", "Low Confidence", "No Answer", "Missing Intent"]
```

Your data should be in an array like this:

```
data: [5, 2, 6, 6]
```

So what ever you are getting from the server needs to be in an array format like above.

Have a look at the [example on the chartjs website](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html).  You can view the code by opening developer tools in your browser.

Or better, read through the [documentation of pie charts on chartjs website](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)

Here is a [jsfiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ce1fn0Lg/), I hard coded the data array in

Comment: yes i know about [5, 2, 6, 6] so thats my question how can i write in that format using my code above?

Comment: i get what you mean in the jsfiddle, but i dont want it to be hardcoded but instead dynamic to call data from database

Comment: data: {!! json_encode($data) !!},

this line above returns one column data, but i need to call the other 3 column, how do i do that?

Comment: php has to be able to return an array to javascript.  I've done it in the past using AJAX, but you could do it on page load.  I've only done it with c#, so I cannot help you with the php part.

Comment: This example may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740775/php-return-array-into-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) for the same purpose. They are easy to handle and can be modified in the similar way as you are doing it.
for dynamic data run a for loop 4 times or data.length times and use data.addRow() method.
You will be able to understand it via its documentation also, if not, here are some modification I can help:

```
var charts = new google.visualization.DataTable();
charts.addColumn('number','questions asked');
charts.addColumn('number','no answer');
charts.addColumn('number','missing intent');

for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
     charts.addRow([$data0])//it should be of array type,so manage it on your own
}
var options = {'title':'anyTitle', 'width':610, 'height':390,legend: {position: 'none'}};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Canvas'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

it will draw a pie chart. Everything else you can learn from google charts api